# Can I use Yii2 classes to get the raw database table schema?

Tags: php, database, yii2, schema

Can I use the Yii2 core classes to read the raw schema for a database table? So that I get the list of columns, types, lengths, etc?

Have tried looking at [yii\db\mysql\Schema](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-mysql-schema) but can't figure out how to use it manually. I know Yii2 does it internally since the models automatically reflect the columns in the table...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Yii::$app->db->getSchema()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-connection#getSchema()-detail) or `Yii::$app->db->schema` to get instance of [`yii\db\Schema`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-schema). Then you can use its `getTableSchema()` method to get instance of [`yii\db\TableSchema`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-tableschema) for specific table and so on.